# Cycle through a loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form in VBA where I want a combo box (cboIncluded) to change its dropdown values according to what's chosen in a different combo box(cboSelectParty).

It provides choices correctly the first time I choose something from cboSelectParty, and if I choose again from either my If or elseif.

My problem is, if I have chosen from either the if or elseif (Fun climb party or climbing party), if won't go back to giving me correct options if I choose anything else.

```
Private Sub cboSelectParty_AfterUpdate()
 
 cboIncluded.Value = ""
    If cboSelectParty.Value = "Fun Climb Party" Then
       cboIncluded.List = Sheets("PartyImport").Range("N3:N4").Value
    ElseIf cboSelectParty.Value = "Climbing Party" Then
       cboIncluded.List = Sheets("PartyImport").Range("O3:O6").Value
    Else
       cboIncluded.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cboSelectParty.Value, 
       Sheets("PartyImport").Range("E2:H37"), 4, False)
    End If   

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. So if you choose first Fun climb party or climbing party it works but won't work a second time? Does the Vlookup work properly?

Comment: That is correct. It even works if I choose anything else first, then choose Fun Climb Party or Climbing Party. But after that if I choose anything else it keeps the choice from Fun Climb Party or Climbing Party.

Comment: You need to debug it Step bu step and see what happens the exact moment it fails. Try executing it with F8 with a breakpoint. https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vba-how-to-debug-code/

Comment: The error message I get is "Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value." , and it points to the line with the vlookup. What is strange is that it works the first time around but errors if I update cboSelectParty a second time.

Comment: The code looks good and the syntax is correct. Maybe another event is causing the trouble? Can you upload the file somewhere to check it out?

Comment: I did manage to find the solution with some help. It turns out in my else cboIncluded.Value was the problem. When it got initialised after having been set as .List it threw the error. My solution was to set it as .List as well and make an array. 
cboIncluded.List = Array(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cboSelectParty.Value, 
       Sheets("PartyImport").Range("E2:H37"), 4, False))